# Spock TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests

Tags: junit, spock

When I was running unit test with Spock, an exception appears：

```
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:134)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1008)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:617)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:708)
    at groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang.StringMetaClass.invokeMethod(StringMetaClass.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1017)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1008)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareToWithEqualityCheck(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:593)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:617)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:708)
    at groovy.runtime.metaclass.java.lang.StringMetaClass.invokeMethod(StringMetaClass.groovy:32)
```

maven version

```
spock-core:2.1-groovy-3.0
spock-reports:2.1.1-groovy-3.0
groovy : 3.0.9
groovy-json : 3.0.10
groovy-xml : 3.0.10
junit:4.12
```

Comment: Please help me !!!!

Comment: Spock 2.x needs JUnit platform 5.x, not JUnit 4.x. Maybe you want to share your full project incl. Maven POM, sample application and sample test code in order to make the problem reproducible in order to get a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I was migrating a microservice from SpringBoot 1.X to 2.X.

Yes, probably is a dependency change that I made, but, in my case I already had the:
`id 'groovy'`

*I started*, with trying to execute directly in a main test folder and I was receiving that message.
Then I was check in each subfolders... Some were executed well... until I found a subfolder with the same message... In the subfolder with problem, I was checking file(class) one by one.
*Finally* I found the class with the problem as you can see in the image.

I put some description and it works...

NOTE: I didn't like empty definition, for this reason a put some description.

Resuming, you could try to search empty definitions with `""()` in directly ***IntelliJ IDEA** (or your IDE)* and not to do it manually as me.

Comment: This is an interesting edge case, but not the case described in the question here. In your stack trace, there is a `PreConditionViolationException` thrown by the JUnit platform, clearly stating _"Method name must not be null or blank"_. That is not the case in the OP's stack trace.

Comment: Sure, I thought would be valuable to Who which had been looking for same initial statement error. `org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests`.

Comment: Sure, it might be valuable to some people, but it simply is not the answer to **this question,** which is why it would have been better to open a **new question,** describing your symptoms, and then answer it yourself with how you spotted the problem in the error message and fixed it.