# TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, spock

Setting up a new Spring Boot project with gradle under IntelliJ-IDA. I am having issues running my spock tests under this configuration. It appears that spock cannot find my unit test.

Here is the stack trace:

```
/opt/java/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:43701,suspend=y,server=n -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-222.3739.54/plugins/Groovy/lib/agent/gragent.jar -javaagent:/opt/idea-IU-222.3739.54/plugins/java/lib/rt/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /opt/idea-IU-222.3739.54/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU-222.3739.54/plugins/junit/lib/junit5-rt.jar:/opt/idea-IU-222.3739.54/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/home/thomas/workspace/farragut-server/build/classes/java/test:/home/thomas/workspace/farragut-server/build/classes/java/main:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.7.3/9e36c7517c4f872b69d0665e1dd46bd6d83c43b7/spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.7.3/ce5a11117ac6c92d38ce071ff2273799862659b7/spring-boot-starter-test-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.7.3/23f7118584200cf9edd43140dc6252679047bee0/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/2.7.3/6b0c093af667bf645cd5f49372e2a2540ae2855f/spring-boot-starter-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.7.3/ea46ce1fc8c0581f2455dcc43a11768660d87388/spring-boot-devtools-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-sql/3.0.9/a70eef193799ed892958ca00c6eda4f8710f656f/groovy-sql-3.0.9.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.spockframework/spock-core/2.1-groovy-3.0/2bd689be193cb26f42692eeef070e6669bebae3e/spock-core-2.1-groovy-3.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy/3.0.10/b92c72a758f468e64b55e38abe06afa873decdba/groovy-3.0.10.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/2.2/3f2bd07716a31c395e2837254f37f21f0f0ab24b/hamcrest-core-2.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.7.3/38c88404d68926aaf6c0914199e8c5e766946de2/spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.7.3/7a5998baaa05d5e7a9af7194a21f2ac3512ba7a0/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/5.3.22/519d86b7ac9b8b6bb54739eb4eb73dc13a263b28/spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/5.3.22/fdab9b8d8df2e6a8fb90f2481c361bcf2c129567/spring-web-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/2.7.3/42924dceee5636b5c12ed36011cc333b40e1f756/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-test/2.7.3/34d3fbf68aa72beef1515ab4a439c23c8c41280e/spring-boot-test-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-test/5.3.22/48375b44c82945e12012ec56dc4090c805b4508b/spring-test-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.3.22/661fc01832716c7eedebf995c6841b2f7117c63d/spring-core-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path/2.7.0/f9d7d9659f2694e61142046ff8a216c047f263e8/json-path-2.7.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/2.3.3/48e3b9cfc10752fba3521d6511f4165bea951801/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.22.0/c300c0c6a24559f35fa0bd3a5472dc1edcd0111e/assertj-core-3.22.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest/2.2/1820c0968dba3a11a1b30669bb1f01978a91dedc/hamcrest-2.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter/5.8.2/5a817b1e63f1217e5c586090c45e681281f097ad/junit-jupiter-5.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/4.5.1/f81fb60bd69b3a6e5537ae23b883326f01632a61/mockito-junit-jupiter-4.5.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.5.1/ed456e623e5afc6f4cee3ae58144e5c45f3b3bf/mockito-core-4.5.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.skyscreamer/jsonassert/1.5.1/6d842d0faf4cf6725c509a5e5347d319ee0431c3/jsonassert-1.5.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.xmlunit/xmlunit-core/2.9.0/8959725d90eecfee28acd7110e2bb8460285d876/xmlunit-core-2.9.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.7.3/b2806bdfae4cff6b82a174a68984a4cedd2d83f5/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.7.3/c5cfc6efad06811d5dd916e86c97989b08575b31/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/2.7.2/1b8783e98d4199c8fbcb46765fbfce02f41907fe/spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.transaction/jakarta.transaction-api/1.3.3/c4179d48720a1e87202115fbed6089bdc4195405/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api/2.2.3/8f6ea5daedc614f07a3654a455660145286f024e/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.6.10.Final/408fd5802391d8e6f619db9d7c6c0e27d49118c2/hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/5.3.22/1fdd8ac7f557ba12bb59086edfe3a9cdf6d918bf/spring-aspects-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.7.3/4c96169e8d71c9c41f07a40d011dbd41898180ac/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.7.3/3a8d641077565b7eaec3b2f91d5b83a6800f5895/spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.7.3/a1e4a13b656182ba10b4c0c7848f91cd6f854fdf/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/1.3.5/59eb84ee0d616332ff44aba065f3888cf002cd2d/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.30/8fde7fe2586328ac3c68db92045e1c8759125000/snakeyaml-1.30.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-engine/1.8.2/b737de09f19864bd136805c84df7999a142fec29/junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.13.3/ad2f4c61aeb9e2a8bb5e4a3ed782cfddec52d972/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.13.3/f71c4ecc1a403787c963f68bc619b78ce1d2687b/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.13.3/d4884595d5aab5babdb00ddbd693b8fd36b5ec3c/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.3/56deb9ea2c93a7a556b3afbedd616d342963464e/jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.65/bd70dfeb39cc83c6934be24fa377b21e541dbe76/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.65/a24c5f379b2ec343a167a83332b75c37f26b2ae7/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.65/d278157387e59a5f9b48091dcada22b7c74aed00/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.65.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/5.3.22/fdd59bb4795c7a399e95ec4a5c8b91103e3189fd/spring-context-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/5.3.22/2f9f00efbff8432f145ccffeb93e6a1819bac362/spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/5.3.22/866c2022b5fef05b1702f4a07cfa5598660ce08a/spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/5.3.22/c056f9e9994b18c95deead695f9471952d1f21d1/spring-expression-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jcl/5.3.22/811ace5e5eb379654ed96fd7844809db51af74a5/spring-jcl-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/6c62681a2f655b49963a5983b8b0950a6120ae14/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.minidev/json-smart/2.4.8/7c62f5f72ab05eb54d40e2abf0360a2fe9ea477f/json-smart-2.4.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api/1.2.2/99f53adba383cb1bf7c3862844488574b559621f/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params/5.8.2/ddeafe92fc263f895bfb73ffeca7fd56e23c2cce/junit-jupiter-params-5.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.8.2/4c21029217adf07e4c0d0c5e192b6bf610c94bdc/junit-jupiter-api-5.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.12.13/35ffee9c24b1c68b08d9207e1a2d3da1add6166/byte-buddy-1.12.13.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/1.12.13/5a4ed1c2eb9e8d7272b36b2b16757e5c653ab650/byte-buddy-agent-1.12.13.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.vaadin.external.google/android-json/0.0.20131108.vaadin1/fa26d351fe62a6a17f5cda1287c1c6110dec413f/android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.7/158f5c255cd3e4408e795b79f7c3fbae9b53b7ca/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/5.3.22/d50fc708ef9bade1d3fb64d529b8ff8cd5b625ba/spring-jdbc-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/4.0.3/107cbdf0db6780a065f895ae9d8fbf3bb0e1c21f/HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/5.3.22/abcefbf4895a3daf263cf385cc66e924db92d254/spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/2.7.2/9547d1234cb380234066aef60129bb2ddfdc6347/spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/5.3.22/d0b3812ab20987a13f3a9ae7b4c54f619e034692/spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.6/1e6cd0e5d9f9919c8c8824fb4d310b09a978a60e/jaxb-runtime-2.3.6.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.1.2.Final/e59ffdbc6ad09eeb33507b39ffcf287679a498c8/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.4.3.Final/c4bd7e12a745c0e7f6cf98c45cdcdf482fd827ea/jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/2.4.2.Final/1e1c385990b258ff1a24c801e84aebbacf70eb39/jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/3fe0bed568c62df5e89f4f174c101eab25345b6c/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/4741689214e9d1e8408b206506cbe76d1c6a7d60/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.17.2/17dd0fae2747d9a28c67bc9534108823d2376b46/log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.36/ed46d81cef9c412a88caef405b58f93a678ff2ca/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-commons/1.8.2/32c8b8617c1342376fd5af2053da6410d8866861/junit-platform-commons-1.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.opentest4j/opentest4j/1.2.0/28c11eb91f9b6d8e200631d46e20a7f407f2a046/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apiguardian/apiguardian-api/1.1.2/a231e0d844d2721b0fa1b238006d15c6ded6842a/apiguardian-api-1.1.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.13.3/7198b3aac15285a49e218e08441c5f70af00fc51/jackson-annotations-2.13.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.13.3/a27014716e4421684416e5fa83d896ddb87002da/jackson-core-2.13.3.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.minidev/accessors-smart/2.4.8/6e1bee5a530caba91893604d6ab41d0edcecca9a/accessors-smart-2.4.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.glassfish.jaxb/txw2/2.3.6/45db7b69a8f1ec2c21eb7d4fc0ee729f53c1addc/txw2-2.3.6.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.istack/istack-commons-runtime/3.0.12/cbbe1a62b0cc6c85972e99d52aaee350153dc530/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.11/a01230df5ca5c34540cdaa3ad5efb012f1f1f792/logback-core-1.2.11.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.17.2/f42d6afa111b4dec5d2aea0fe2197240749a4ea6/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/9.1/a99500cf6eea30535eeac6be73899d048f8d12a8/asm-9.1.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.h2database/h2/2.1.214/d5c2005c9e3279201e12d4776c948578b16bf8b2/h2-2.1.214.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.12.8/aa42edb39e624cbf8a5b33cb5c5e920027cee42b/byte-buddy-1.12.8.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/3.2/7fadf57620c8b8abdf7519533e5527367cb51f09/objenesis-3.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-testkit/1.8.2/43c593ad99a975588d56b501fd4353065facebfc/junit-platform-testkit-1.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/20.1.0/2fcd1f3225bca0c4a7bc931142076f8c1e80993f/annotations-20.1.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.ow2.asm/asm/9.2/81a03f76019c67362299c40e0ba13405f5467bff/asm-9.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/cglib/cglib-nodep/3.3.0/87271c95d5bc9e37e4981c9593ff14d470b6684b/cglib-nodep-3.3.0.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine/5.8.2/c598b4328d2f397194d11df3b1648d68d7d990e3/junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher/1.8.2/c334fcee82b81311ab5c426ec2d52d467c8d0b28/junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:/home/thomas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.2/74548703f9851017ce2f556066659438019e7eb5/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account.AccountTest
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:43701', transport: 'socket'
Internal Error occurred.
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:134)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account.AccountTest'] resolution failed
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:82)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.SpockEngine.discover(SpockEngine.java:28)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:152)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account.AccountTest
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.lambda$getJavaClass$0(ClassSelector.java:75)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try$Failure.getOrThrow(Try.java:335)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.ClassSelector.getJavaClass(ClassSelector.java:74)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:26)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:134)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:185)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:91)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account.AccountTest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.lambda$tryToLoadClass$9(ReflectionUtils.java:829)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try.lambda$call$0(Try.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try.of(Try.java:93)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.function.Try.call(Try.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.tryToLoadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:792)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.tryToLoadClass(ReflectionUtils.java:748)
    ... 32 more
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:43701', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 254
```

I've been digging for a couple of days and found many related issues and have made sure my groovy directory is marked as test source root and have invalidated cache and restarted a number of times. I am running my unit tests as IntelliJ IDEA and also found the following similar error: [Spock TestEngine with ID 'spock' failed to discover tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72151417/spock-testengine-with-id-spock-failed-to-discover-tests#_=)_ which did not have a solution.

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:2.1.214'

    // mandatory dependencies for using Spock
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.10'
    testImplementation platform("org.spockframework:spock-bom:2.1-groovy-3.0")
    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core"

    // optional dependencies for using Spock
    testImplementation "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:2.2"   // only necessary if Hamcrest matchers are used
    testRuntimeOnly 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.12.8' // allows mocking of classes (in addition to interfaces)
    testRuntimeOnly "org.objenesis:objenesis:3.2"      // allows mocking of classes without default constructor (together with ByteBuddy or CGLIB)

    // dependencies used by examples in this project
    implementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:3.0.9"
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()

    testLogging {
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}
```

It acts like my AccountTest is not on my classpath somehow, but scratching my head as to what I've missed.

Here is my test:

```
package com.heavyweightsoftware.farragut.server.pojo.account

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.time.ZonedDateTime

class AccountTest extends Specification {
    Account account;

    static Account getAccount() {
        Account result = new Account()

        return result;
    }

    void setup() {
        account = getAccount()
    }

    def "getStartTime should never be null"() {
        when: "retrieving a start date"
        ZonedDateTime start = account.getStartTime()

        then: "should never be null"
        start != null
    }
}
```

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `id 'java'` with `id 'groovy'` so Gradle knows you have Groovy stuff to compile?

Comment: @tim_yates Yeah, I think that did it. I at least have new errors to work on. Do you want to post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Done!  Yay!  And thanks!  (in that order) 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To run spock tests, you need the Groovy plugin (so it knows to look for Groovy sourcesets and use the Groovy compiler)

Change

```
  id 'java'
```

To

```
  id 'groovy'
```

In your plugins (the groovy plugin includes the java plugin as part of it's application)